# Huggingface progress bars shown despite disable_tqdm=True in Trainer

Tags: python, progress-bar, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I'm running HuggingFace Trainer with TrainingArguments(disable_tqdm=True, ...) for fine-tuning the EleutherAI/gpt-j-6B model but there are still progress bars displayed (please see picture below). Does somebody know how to remove these progress bars?

```
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    disable_tqdm=True,
    output_dir='./checkpoints',
    save_total_limit=10,
    logging_dir='/content/logs',
    num_train_epochs=config["N_EPOCHS"],
    evaluation_strategy='epoch'
    save_strategy='steps',
    save_steps=30,
    logging_steps=10,
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    per_device_train_batch_size=4,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=4,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=4,
    eval_accumulation_steps=4,
    gradient_checkpointing=True,
    max_grad_norm=0.5,
    lr_scheduler_type="cosine",
    learning_rate=1e-4,
    warmup_ratio=0.05,
    weight_decay=0.1,
    fp16_full_eval=True
    fp16=True,
    fp16_opt_level='O1',
    report_to=['tensorboard']
)
```

[image]